# Same element name in two different xsd files

Tags: xml, web-services, xpath, xsd, xjb

I have two xsd files.However , the element name is same in both files.
So , to overcome from conflicts I have created binding file.

**Request.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="XML">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="HEADER"/>
        <xs:element ref="TOUR_OP"/>
        <xs:element ref="CUSTOMERID"/>
        <xs:element ref="DATEDEP"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="HEADER" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="TOUR_OP" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="CUSTOMERID" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="DATEDEP" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**Response.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="XML">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="HEADER"/>
        <xs:element ref="RESULTS"/>
        <xs:element ref="ENV"/>
        <xs:element ref="APP"/>
        <xs:element ref="VER"/>
        <xs:element ref="STAMP"/>
        <xs:element ref="CLIENT"/>
        <xs:element ref="PIN"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="HEADER" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="RESULTS">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="AEROPLANS"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="AEROPLANS">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="AEROPLAN"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="AEROPLAN">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="MARKETCD"/>
        <xs:element ref="AEROPOINT"/>
        <xs:element ref="AERODOLLARS"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="MARKETCD" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="AEROPOINT" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="AERODOLLARS" type="xs:decimal"/>
  <xs:element name="ENV" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="APP" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="VER" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
  <xs:element name="STAMP" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="CLIENT" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="PIN" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**Binding File (XJB)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
          version="2.1">

        <bindings schemaLocation="TTSAeroplanPointsSuccessResponse_v1.0.xsd">
            <bindings node=".//xsi:attribute[@name='XML']">
                <class name="XMLResponse"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
</bindings>
```

As you can see , I both xsd files contain element name="XML" and binding file is created to overcome the conflicts while generating model classes.

I am getting an Error : XPath evaluation of ".//xsi:attribute[@name='XML']" results in empty target node

Please advice me , how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two XML elements are distinct, consider using different names - RequestXml, ResponseXml.  Much simpler since you won't need to use binding.  Keep It Simple principal in action!

Comment: What about the HEADER. Should I change it to ResponseHeader and RequestHeader

Comment: How? Can you give example